# Are modular Collatz graphs strongly connected?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

A while ago, I stumbled on the idea of representing the Collatz function, modulo a prime $p$, as a directed graph. Define, as usual
$$
T(x) = \begin{cases}
(3x+1)/2 & \text{if $x$ is odd,} \\
x/2 & \text{if $x$ is even.} \\
\end{cases}
$$

We can consider $T(x)$ mod $p$, by letting $\frac{1}{2} \equiv 2^{-1} \equiv \frac{p+1}{2} \pmod{p}$. I haven’t the means to draw it, but a modular Collatz graph mod $7$ would have even edges
$$
\begin{align}
0 &\to 0 \\
1 &\to 4 \to 2 \to 1 \\
3 &\to 5 \to 6 \to 3
\end{align}
$$

and odd edges
$$
\begin{align}
0 &\to 4 \to 3 \to 5 \to 1 \to 2 \to 0 \\
6 &\to 6\text{.}
\end{align}
$$

The term “modular Collatz graph” comes from the paper [The Collatz conjecture and De Bruijn graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3495). I am unable to understand that paper but I did glean that my “discovery” was in fact wholly unoriginal. Here, I must further reveal that my understanding of mathematics is very primitive, the simplest concepts I find hard to grasp. When I asked a beginner level question at MathOverflow I was chastised for disturbing the sanctity of that august body; I can only hope this forum will be more patient. I do not intend my lack of smarts to be offensive.

What I observed about modular Collatz graphs, mod $p$, is that they seem always to be strongly connected, i.e. from any node you can hop to any other. But how to prove this? I contacted a professional mathematician who showed extraordinary kindness and supplied the proof below. I am not free to name this person but I do have permission to share the proof. You must keep in mind that the proof given to me was simplified in order to make it accessible to me. Unfortunately, I still do not understand it.

My questions about this matter are:

1. Are modular Collatz graphs strongly connected?
2. Is the proof below correct?
3. Are there any other proofs?

Here's the proof I was given:

> Let $p$ be a prime. Mapping $x \to f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ could be seen as multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ or by $2^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. For the function $g$ mapping $x \to g(x) = \frac{3x+1}{2} \pmod{p}$, note that this is equivalent to saying that $(x+1)$ is mapped to $g(x+1) = \frac{3x+1}{2} + 1 = \frac{3}{2}(x+1) \pmod{p}$. Alternatively, $x$ is mapped to $g(x) = \frac{3}{2}(x+1) - 1 \pmod{p}$.
>
> Now suppose that starting at a point $x_1$, we can reach a set of points $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\}$ by hopping through the graph, and we cannot reach any other points besides these $k$ points. Consider the sum $S = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \pmod{p}$. As both $f$ and $g$ are permutations, we have (working modulo $p$)
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> S &= x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \\
> &= f(x_1) + f(x_2) + \cdots + f(x_k) \\
> &= \frac{1}{2}S
> \end{split}
> $$
>   and also
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> S &= x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \\
> &= g(x_1) + g(x_2) + \cdots + g(x_k) \\
> &= \frac{3}{2}(S + k) - k \\
> &= \frac{3}{2}S + \frac{3}{2}k - k\text{.}
> \end{split}
> $$
>   From $S = \frac{S}{2}$ it follows that $S$ must be $0$ modulo $p$. From $0 = S = \frac{3S}{2} + \frac{3k}{2} - k = \frac{k}{2}$ it follows that $k$ is also $0$ modulo $p$. So if we have a connected component of size $k$, then $k$ must be either $0$ (nothing) or $p$ (the entire graph.) So indeed, starting from any point ($k > 1$), its connected component must be of size $p$ (the entire graph.)

Comment: I suggest using MathJax to typeset your formulas: it is difficult to read the last part of your question.

Comment: I do not know who edited my question but it looks terrific! Such generosity rather amazes me. Thank you so much.